# bash-completion: how to select among different alternatives

Tags: bash, auto-completion

In bash, how can I select an option from a list displayed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

Ex. Suppose `vim <TAB>` shows different possibilities `txt1 txt2 txt3`. How can I select the first one (`txt1`)?

**EDIT:**

let me be more precise by further elaborating the previous example:

Suppose that the current folder contains only a file named `txt1`. If I write `vim t<TAB>`, the autocompletion correctly works, i.e. it displays `vim txt1`.

However, if the folder contains three files `txt1`, `txt2`, `txt3`, the command `vim t<TAB>` displays only `txt1 txt2 txt3`, without any autocompletion.

How can I get the autocompletion to happen even in the latter case?

Comment: Do you mean without typing the name (and autocomplete)?

Comment: Yes. Pressing <TAB> displays the names only but does not provide any autocompletion.

Comment: something like this : [cycle through suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/terminal-autocomplete-cycle-through-suggestions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash works the next way:

```
$ touch file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt video1.avi video2.avi
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  video1.avi  video2.avi
```

If you input the first letter `f` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> the first time, it autocompletes it to `file`. If you hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> the second time, it shows all available variants starting with `file`. There're three files starting with `file` prefix and `bash` does not know which of them you want.

```
$ vim.tiny file                    # the second tab
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
```

Then, if you input the next symbol and there's no other files starting with it, it autocompletes it fully:

- `$ vim.tiny file`<kbd>1</kbd>`#   1 added to 'file' word`
- `$ vim.tiny file1`
- <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- `$ vim.tiny file1.txt  #   result`

If you want it to work similarly as it is in `zsh`, you could execute the next commands:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

It will behave the next way:

- `$ vim.tiny f`
- <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Result:

  ```
  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  
  $ vim.tiny file1.txt
  ```
- <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Result: `$ vim.tiny file2.txt`

Comment: It would be clearer is there were a `<kbd>1</kbd>` somewhere.

Comment: Does exists some way to "navigate" through the possibilities, similarly to zsh?

Comment: What do you mean *navigate through the possibilities*? I've just installed `zsh` and tried TAB key and it works the same way as bash do when you are in the folder with files.

Comment: Pressing TAB twice allows you to navigate through the possible completion displayed by the first TAB. Perhaps this comes with oh-my-zsh installed too. I sincerely do not remember now.

Comment: Yes, really. First time it autocompletes to `file`, second time it shows all possible variants starting from `file`, the third time it autocompletes to `file1.txt`, the fourth time it switches to `file2.txt` and so on circularly to `file3.txt`, `file1.txt`, ...